# Kotlin - Issue in getting location from Network provider

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location, android-gps

I must have to take location from the user device in my Android application.

I have done something as below :

**First**, I have checked for the Runtime Location Permissions. Taken successfully.

**Second**, Checking that GPS is enabled or not and if GPS PROVIDER is working fine, am able to fetch latitude and longitude from the GPS Provider.

**Third**, If GPS is off, am trying to get location from the NETWORK Provider.
But, in this case sometimes am not able fetch location successfully.

So, I must have let the user to turn the GPS on and have to get the location after turning on the GPS.

I am confused because many demos provides INTENTS for turning the GPS on. 
How can I turn the GPS on dynamically ? 
How can I get notified that user turned on the GPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Gradle plugin, In my case, it was version: '17.0.0'

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$parent.ext.playServicesVersion"
```

And Here is the `GpsUtils` Class,

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class GpsUtils {

    private Context context;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final String TAG = GpsUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    public GpsUtils(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(2 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************
    }

    // method for turn on GPS
    public void turnGPSOn(onGpsListener onGpsListener) {

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
            }
        } else {
            mSettingsClient
                    .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                            //  GPS is already enable, callback GPS status through listener
                            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener((Activity) context, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                                    try {
                                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context, Appconstants.GPS_REQUEST);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                        "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";

                                    Toast.makeText((Activity) context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public interface onGpsListener {
        void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable);
    }
}
```

and you can call the below function from your activity to let the user enable GPS. I kept GPSUtils class in java itself as it is interoperable.

```
  GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn { isGPSEnable ->
                isGPS = isGPSEnable  // You can get the callback here..
            }
```

You can read more about `SettingsClient` from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient).

Comment: Hello Sir, I found the way to show the GPS dialog. Now, the question is How Can I get notify that user pressed OK or NOT NOW ?

Comment: If they press `OK`, eventually you will get GPS enabled and vice versa right? What do you want to achieve with that "Yes" or "No" Btn clicked?  Anyhow, `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` may help you?